# Sequelize generates some random alias in production build

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, vercel

The following query works just fine on local env with dev build (next.js app) though starts generating some random alias for Payments table when executed on prod build (deployed using Vercel). Basically, Sequelize generates a query with `as "gs"` for `Payments` table.

```
const existingBooking = await BookingRequests.findByPk(id, {
   include: [
     { model: SectorBookings, include: [Payments] },
     { model: BookingComments, attributes: ["text"] },
   ],
 });
```

There is many-to-many association between `Payments` and `SectorBookings`

```
SectorBookings.belongsToMany(Payments, {
  through: SectorBookingPayments,
  foreignKey: "sectorBookingId",
  otherKey: "paymentId",
});
Payments.belongsToMany(SectorBookings, {
  through: SectorBookingPayments,
  foreignKey: "paymentId",
  otherKey: "sectorBookingId",
});
```

Comment: So it generates an alias what is the problem? What is your question?

Comment: Looks like you have different values on `dev` and on `prod` environment for `minifyAliases` option while creating Sequelize instance

Comment: The issue is that those aliases creates issues when adding conditions to the query. I managed to fix it by providing modelName. Might be that it was caused by minification where models were renamed - that's my guess. I'll check and will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue when using next@14.0.3 but goes away if I use next@13.5.6.

I haven't determined exactly why this is the case yet, but my intuition is that the minifier is doing something strange.

EDIT w/ Solutions

I found the solution and the most likely reason this is happening. It looks like the swc minifier is minifying the class names of sequelize models. Sequelize by default uses the class name for determining the `modelName` which is what is used by default in queries.

Solution:

Every model class created in sequelize should have `modelName` directly defined. That way the class name has no bearing on the final name used inside of sequelize queries.

Here is a sample configuration that shows the change necessary

```
class TestModel extends Model<InferAttributes<TestModel>, InferCreationAttributes<TestModel>> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare title: string;
}

TestModel.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  },
  {
    // THIS IS THE FIX
    modelName: 'TestModel',
    sequelize
  }
);
```